# Simple way to apply template to existing HTML code

Tags: java, html

Suppose I have a bunch of (very simple) HTML pages, that I want to apply a common 'theme".

These files are downloaded using various Groovy scripts, and I would like to apply to them this styling during a maven build. How could I do that ?
Using which framework/library could I do that ?

Furthermore notice I want to do that in a static fashion, that's to say I want to have the following process to occur

1. Files are downloaded by Groovy scripts
2. They are processed (in a "magical" fashion) by this library
3. They may be sent by FTP/SCP to an hosting server

Do you know such an easy to use library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using sitemesh decorator. I am a user of old version but a new release is being worked on that allows you to do exactly what you are asking for. Do a google search on sitemesh and you should find lots of examples.

In a nutshell sitemesh decoration: basic html + template = decorated page.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the details of the task but having in mind the steps you've described you can consider using velocity templates.